# How to avoid defined para from appearing at bottom of page?

Tags: positioning, page-breaking

I defined a poem-environment for two lined poems with the macro below. And could get both lines unbroken with `samepage` environment.

But how do I make them to not end on last line of a page.

```
\def\shloka{\bgroup\bfseries\begin{flushleft}\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont\leftskip=10pt\begin{samepage}}
\def\endshloka{\end{samepage}\end{flushleft}\egroup}
```

Comment: You can use [the `needspace` package](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/needspace/), and use `\needspace{r\baselineskip}` to reserve at least three lines so that it won't end of the last line of the page.

Answer (score 6):

Without the use of any extra package it can be done as follows:

```
<material without pagebreak, e.g., your two line poem>
\vspace*{\baselineskip}%
\allowbreak
\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
\vspace{0pt}%
```

Explanation:

- the first `\vspace*` adds a vertical space without adding a break possibility before
- at the `\allowbreak` LaTeX will check if the page can be broken here. If this makes the page overfull LaTeX will break before your poem. If it is a possible breakpoint it will be recorded as such and possibly chosen later as the best one (in which case one baselineskip of space would end up at the bottom)
- if the break is chosen at this point then the following two vertical spaces will vanish into the page break
- then we back up so that we are directly after the last line of text to typeset further material without this extra space.
- the `\vspace{0pt}` is only added to guard against something like `\addvspace` that should not "see" our artificial negative space.